# Calendar Hour component is 5 hours ahead, Unable to adjust it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, calendar

I have two components in my app. A UIDATEPICKER that is set to select the time only, HOURS AND MINUTES. and A calendar (FSCALENDAR 3rd party) that selects the date,month and year for me. I am trying to combine the time selected from a uidatepicker and the date selected from the calendar to create a notification. it is working so far but the hour is 5 hours ahead. i think it is because of the 12 hour format of the uidatepicker. how do i extract the hour component in 24 hours format?

The code below is for extracting the date and time.

```
class ReminderViewController: UIViewController, FSCalendarDelegate, FSCalendarDataSource {
    var reminderDate : String?
    var reminderDay : Int?
    var reminderMonth : Int?
    var reminderYear : Int?
    var reminderHour : Int?
    var reminderMinute : Int?

    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var rDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBAction func reminderDatePicker(_ sender: Any) {
            var df = DateFormatter()
            let date = rDatePicker.date
            let dateAsString = df.string(from: date)
            let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)
            reminderHour = components.hour!
            reminderMinute = components.minute!
        
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var doneButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func doneAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let totalComponents = NSDateComponents()
        totalComponents.day = reminderDay!
        totalComponents.hour = reminderHour!
        totalComponents.month = reminderMonth!
        totalComponents.minute = reminderMinute!
        totalComponents.year = reminderYear!
          let finalDate = calendar.date(from: totalComponents as DateComponents)
          print(finalDate)
    }
    
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500).isActive = true
        reminderCalendar.delegate = self
        reminderCalendar.dataSource = self
        
    let totalComponents = NSDateComponents()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let date = Date()
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .month, .day , .year], from: date)
    reminderHour = components.hour!
    reminderMinute = components.minute!
    reminderMonth = components.month!
    reminderDay = components.day!
    reminderYear = components.year!
    
    let finalDate = calendar.date(from: components as DateComponents)
    print("FINAL" , finalDate)
    
    }

    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
            print(date)
            var df = DateFormatter()
            df = DateFormatter()
            df.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
            reminderDate =  df.string(from: date)
            reminderMonth = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date)
            reminderDay = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: date)
            reminderYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: date)
        
        print(reminderMonth)
        print(reminderYear)
        print(reminderDay)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a date and time  and Convert it in UST format based on your timezone you are ahead that's why it create issue

```
    func localToUTC(date:String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    dateFormatter.calendar = NSCalendar.current
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current

    let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    return dateFormatter.string(from: dt!)
}


func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
        print(date)
        var df = DateFormatter()
        df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "yyyy:MM:dd:HH:mm:ss"
        reminderDate =  df.string(from: date)
        reminderMonth = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date)
        reminderDay = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: date)
        reminderYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: date)
    
    print(reminderMonth)
    print(reminderYear)
    print(reminderDay)
}
```